# I am unable to execute a hive script

Tags: hive

I want to know what is the command to execute a hive Script

Complete the Code to execute the hive script ./custexport.hql
Scripts hive>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hive then

```
hive -f 'your hql file'
```

if you are using beeline then also you can use -f option with complete beeline command.

Comment: Thank you Manu for your response. I am new to hive.  Actually the question reads like this :

" Complete the code to execute the Hive Script
  
  Scripts hive> ________________ ./custexport.hql".  

I did try with hive -f but it says incorrect.  Please advise

Comment: Try it with unix shell. Don't go into hive shell. hive -f will take it to hive shell itself.